# How can I print the link to the media file?

Tags: theming, media, 9

I have an image media type. I would like to display the image and the link to the file in the rendered Media. I don't want the image to be a link to the file.

I couldn't find a link to the file field in *Manage display*. I looked at the media.html.twig file, but I could not understand how to link to the file.

How can I add the media file link in *Manage display*?

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to present a media item.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - media: The media item, with limited access to object properties and
 *   methods. Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and
 *   a few common methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available.
 *   For example:
 *   - entity.getEntityTypeId() will return the entity type ID.
 *   - entity.hasField('field_example') returns TRUE if the entity includes
 *     field_example. (This does not indicate the presence of a value in this
 *     field.)
 *   Calling other methods, such as entity.delete(), will result in
 *   an exception.
 *   See \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface for a full list of methods.
 * - name: Name of the media item.
 * - content: Media content.
 * - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - view_mode: View mode; for example, "teaser" or "full".
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 * - title_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main title
 *   tag that appears in the template.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_media()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<div{{ attributes }}>
  {{ title_suffix.contextual_links }}
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

Comment: `{{ file_url(media.field_media_image.entity.fileuri) }}` maybe?

Comment: With Twig Tweak maybe even `{{ media_file_url(media) }}` or `{{ media|file_url }}` works. https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak/issues/2924925 or https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image/issues/2856093

Comment: Found all that in 10 seconds on Google.

Comment: thank you, it works

Comment: Which one? Add it as answer.